# Please explain History Monoid in Simpler Terms

Tags: math, concurrency, synchronization, computer-science

I tried to read the History monoid but couldn't wrap my head around it. Could somebody please explain it in simpler terms?

Thank you

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_monoid

Comment: [cstheory.stackexchange](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) is a better place for such questions.

Comment: Essentially what they are doing is projecting from the free monoid over the union of a set of alphabets into the cartesian product of the free monoids over the individual alphabets. The history monoid is then the submonoid of said product generated by the image of the projection. If you want something clearer than that, you're going to have to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The history monoid is the set of possible sequences of primitive actions in the threads, taking into account synchronization primitives which occur in more than one thread simultaneously.

Actually it is not just a set but a monoid, which means that you can concatenate the sequences to get a new sequence in the monoid, and there is a neutral element, the empty sequence.